# static pointer overflow in bss

Tags: pointers, static, overflow, address-sanitizer

I'm using w00w00 exercises on static pointer overflow in bss. I put the buffer and buffer pointer into static struct to force overflowing the pointer. Otherwise, it put the pointer before and buffer and no overflow happens.

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <unistd.h>
   #include <string.h>
   #include <errno.h>

   #define BUFSIZE 16
   #define ADDRLEN 4 /* # of bytes in an address */


int main()
   {
        u_long diff;
    struct buf {
    char buf[BUFSIZE];
    char *bufptr  ;
    } ;

    static struct buf a;

    a.bufptr = a.buf, diff = (u_long)a.buf - (u_long)&a.bufptr;

    printf("bufptr (%p) = %p, buf = %p, diff = 0x%x (%d) bytes\n",
            &a.bufptr,a.bufptr, a.buf, diff, diff);

    memset(a.buf, 'A', (u_int)(diff + ADDRLEN));

    printf("bufptr (%p) = %p, buf = %p, diff = 0x%x (%d) bytes\n",
            &a.bufptr, a.bufptr, a.buf, diff, diff);

      return 0;
   }
```

I'm currently getting this error when I used AddressSanitizer

```
==27643==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: negative-size-param: (size=-12)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: negative-size-param ??:0 __asan_memset
==27643==ABORTING
```

Is there a flag or way to force the overflow?

---

**Edit:**
**I figured out the problem. Diff result was -16. 
I mad it look like this**

```
diff = (u_long)&a.bufptr - (u_long)a.buf
```

Now it work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try size which is larger than struct size but not large enough to be interpreted as negative:

```
memset(a.buf, 'A', 1024);
```

Also be sure to compile with `-fno-common` as explained in [Asan FAQ](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer#faq).